# JavaScript error - "Cannot read properties of undefined" in Shopify theme

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm encountering a JavaScript error in my Shopify theme related to variant selection. The error message is "Cannot read properties of undefined." The issue seems to be occurring at line 1226 in the global.js file. I'm using a variant-radios element for color selection and a variant-selects element for size selection on the product page. The error is preventing the selected variant from working correctly.

Below is the relevant code:

```
{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <variant-radios
    class="no-js-hidden"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    data-url="{{ product.url }}"
    {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      <fieldset name="Color" class="js product-form__input {% unless option.name == 'Color' %} %}hidden{% endunless %}">

        <legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}</legend>

        {%- for value in option.values -%}


          {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
              name="{{ option.name }}"
              value="{{ value | escape }}"
              form="{{ product_form_id }}"
              {% if option.selected_value == value %}
              checked
              {% endif %}>
          {% endif %}


          {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
            {% assign variant_image_url = product.variants[forloop.index0].metafields.variant.image_url %}
            <label
              class="swColor"
              for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
              style="background-image: url({{ variant_image_url }});">
              {{ value }}
            </label>
          {% endif %}


        {%- endfor -%}
      </fieldset>
    {%- endfor -%}
    <script type="application/json">
      {{ product.variants | json }}
    </script>
  </variant-radios>

  <variant-selects
    id="variant-selects-{{ section.id }}"
    class="no-js-hidden"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    data-url="{{ product.url }}"
    {% if update_url == false %}
    data-update-url="false"
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
    {% for option in product.options_with_values %}

      {% if option.name == 'Size' %}
        <label for="Option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
        <div class="my-2">
          <select
            name="options[{{ option.name | escape }}]"
            id="Option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
            class="w-full border py-3 px-3">
            {% for value in option.values %}
              <option
                value="{{ value | escape }}"
                {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                selected="selected"
                {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>

            {% endfor %}


          </select>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <script type="application/json">
        {{ product.variants | json }}
      </script>

    {% endfor %}

  </variant-selects>
{%- endunless -%}

class VariantRadios extends VariantSelects {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  setInputAvailability(listOfOptions, listOfAvailableOptions) {
    listOfOptions.forEach((input) => {
      if (listOfAvailableOptions.includes(input.getAttribute('value'))) {
        input.classList.remove('disabled');
      } else {
        input.classList.add('disabled');
      }
    });
  }

  updateOptions() {
    const fieldsets = Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('fieldset'));
    this.options = fieldsets.map((fieldset) => {
      return Array.from(fieldset.querySelectorAll('input')).find((radio) => radio.checked).value;
    });
  }
}
```

The error log mentions an issue in the VariantRadios.updateOptions method. I've already tried updating the code based on suggestions, but the problem persists. Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!